# Single User, Different Roles In Different Clients in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have a user which works with different clients.

So I have client database separated.

I need different roles per as different client has different permission to provide to the user.

So is this possible in ASP.Net Authorization. If Yes. Then How?

I am using ASP.Net Core MVC.

I want to protect my MVC views based on roles.

Comment: you can use Authorization filter for this.. By Inheriting AuthorizeAttribute class, you can write your custom logic there.  This link might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: @user2864740 This was for protecting view. I have updated question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I was googling wrong way. I got my answer from following.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authorize